# Reading unicode objects as a string

Tags: python, json, unicode, beautifulsoup

I have an excel sheet crawled from a website using beautifulsoup and printed that unicode object result as it is into csv like

> {u'rgb': u'190,190,190', u'type': u'INTERIOR', u'name': u'Orchid, premium leather'}, {u'rgb': u'60,79,77', u'type': u'EXTERIOR', u'name': u'Nord Gray Metallic'}

But now I'm not able to read them using pandas as a dictionary as it is returning single strings like '{',"u".

I tried encoding the string too but no result.
I want to read the dictionaries as it is.

Comment: Since you tagged `json`, use `json.dumps()` to write the dictionary to a CSV, and `json.loads` to convert the string back to a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You cant append `"["` and  `"]"` characters to the string. And then use `eval()` to convert it into a list of dicts:

```
f = open("data.csv", "r")
data_string = "[" + f.read() + "]"
data_list = eval(data_string)

for data in data_list:
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function from the [**ast**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
d = "{u'rgb': u'190,190,190', u'type': u'INTERIOR', u'name': u'Orchid, premium leather'}, {u'rgb': u'60,79,77', u'type': u'EXTERIOR', u'name': u'Nord Gray Metallic'}"
d = list(ast.literal_eval(d))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                      name          rgb      type
0  Orchid, premium leather  190,190,190  INTERIOR
1       Nord Gray Metallic     60,79,77  EXTERIOR
```

Comment: File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string

Comment: Can you post some of your data. Looks like the string are having some irregularities.

Comment: {u'rgb': u'158,13,23', u'type': u'EXTERIOR', u'name': u'San Marino Red'}, {u'rgb': u'0,0,0', u'type': u'INTERIOR', u'name': u'Ebony, premium leather'}, {u'rgb': u'212,194,160', u'type': u'INTERIOR', u'name': u'Parchment, premium leather'}, {u'rgb': u'60,72,110', u'type': u'EXTERIOR', u'name': u'Fathom Blue Pearl'}, {u'rgb': u'73,74,76', u'type': u'EXTERIOR', u'name': u'Modern Steel Metallic'}

Comment: df['colors'][0] of my csv looks like this.

Comment: I crawled the data from website and wrote parts of json directly to csv. It is printed as unicode object because I didnt do any encoding. I want to read each unicode objects as a list element or as a single string but it is returning me a single letter as a string.